# I have only 1970-01-1.. when I use ifNull

Tags: sql, clickhouse, ifnull

In ClickHouse, I want to write fix 'dateTime' where column (type: DateTime64(9)) is null but I have only 1970-01-01...

[image]

`select Id, ifnull(event_datetime, toDateTime64('2023-06-20',9,'Etc/UTC')) as event_datetime from ...`

I wrote the correct timeZone like I have in the table, wrote the correct number of 0 after the dot, and checked that I haven't put limits for rewrite values in the table.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that in ClickHouse, "NULL" is only used with the Nullable data type: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nullable - this is a special data type if you want to essentially store a string value of "NULL" rather than an empty field.

In general, I suspect what you trying to do is check for an empty field, or in the case of DateTime, check for '1970-01-01 00:00:00'. Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT Id, toDateTime64('2023-06-20',9)
FROM dateTest
WHERE event_datetime = '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Thank you for anwer! Unfortunately, no. I want to change all NULL values in Nullable DateTime64(9) column to '2023-06-20 00:00:00' or now() , it's doesn't matter. I use ifnull(event_datetime, toDateTime64('2023-06-20',9,'Etc/UTC') for it but I have only 1970-01-01 instead of  '2023-06-20 00:00:00'.

Comment: please show an example of what is currently in that column, such as just a set of those rows where at least one has no value/NULL - example:

SELECT Id, event_datetime
FROM dateTest
LIMIT 20;

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    Id, if(event_datetime == toDateTime64('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', 9), toDateTime64('2023-06-20', 9), event_datetime) AS event_datetime
FROM
    table;
```